# What does algebraic number look like locally?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is there any theorem characterizing what algebraic number looks like locally (in completion)? For example, do all algebraic numbers live in some $\mathbb{Q}_p$? Does there exist algebraic number in extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree p, say?

Comment: Algebraic numbers live in $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ (some fixed construction of the algebraic closure), and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not a subfield of this (for cardinality reasons). So I am not sure what you mean by living in some $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Maybe you are asking: does any algebraic equation over $\mathbb{Q}$ have solutions in some $\mathbb{Q}_p$? Can you make the question more precise please? (Am I missing some obvious interpretation?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me formulate your question (or rather one of your questions) this way: if $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)\supset\mathbb Q$ is a finite extension, is there an embedding $K\to\mathbb Q_p$ for some $p$? The answer is yes; supposing without loss of generality that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer, if $f\in\mathbb Z[x]$ is the monic minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, there are infinitely many $p$'s such that the reduction of $f$ mod $p$ has a root in $\mathbb F_p$ (one can use the nuke called Chebotarev's density theorem to see it, but I guess there are simpler proofs). Take such a $p$ not dividing the discriminant of $f$, and by Hensel lemma $f$ will have a root in $\mathbb Q_p$.

Comment: Can I ask if $\alpha$ could be in an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: @Vladimir It was cooked up so that $\alpha$ is in $\mathbb Q_p$. In general, if $f$ mod $p$ doesn't split to linear factors in $\mathbb F_p[x]$, $\alpha$ gets sent to elements algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$ (the degree of the extension is the degree of the irreducible factor of $f$ mod $p$).

Answer (score -1):

$x^2 + 1 = 0$ does not have a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_3$ since $0^2 + 1 = 1$ and  $1^2 + 1 = 2^2 + 1 = 2 \text{ mod } 3$.